# Why can't I pass sha1 output to gmp_init()?

Tags: php, math, radix, gmp

I was checking out the binary parameter of [sha1](http://php.net/sha1) today and I was not able to convert the resulting binary string to a base 62 representation.

```
$str = 'mystring';
echo gmp_strval(gmp_init(sha1($str), 16), 62), PHP_EOL;      // Works
echo gmp_strval(gmp_init(sha1($str, true), 2), 62), PHP_EOL; // Fails
// Same with base_convert()...
echo base_convert(sha1($str), 16, 32), PHP_EOL;              // Works
echo base_convert(sha1($str, true), 2, 32), PHP_EOL;         // Fails
```

Result:

```
MNun4i9wmY2M2sBvnq5Z8jDi7nk
0
jjhukjbflgg000000000000000000000
0
```

I'm wondering if it is because the [gmp_init()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-init.php) and [base_convert()](http://php.net/base_convert) functions requires an integer or string and this is perhaps just binary data.

Comment: `sha1($str, TRUE)` with return actual raw `\?pi"@*HDTF}` binary output, not a `10101100110` binary digits result..

Comment: @mario, then how can I convert it into binary digits?

Comment: You can only use the workaround over the hex output. `base_convert` notably could be used to get a dual system representation, but internally converts to floats first IIRC, so is useless in your case. So I'd keep feeding hex numbers into gmp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mario comment is correct, to convert from a binary string representation to base 2, you must do:

```
$base2 = array_map('decbin', array_map('ord', str_split(sha1($str, true))));
```

Or from the hexadecimal digest:

```
$base2 = array_map('decbin', array_map('hexdec', str_split(sha1($str), 2)));
```

Then all you need to do is zero-pad each `$base2` value to 8 bits and implode it's contents.

---

It's also worth noticing that your `base_convert` call will overflow, so don't rely on it.

One other (rather important) thing is that the charset `gmp` uses for base > 10 is actually:

```
0123456789A..Za..z
```

Contrary to what the `base_convert` and hash functions use of:

```
0123456789a..f[g..zA..Z]
```

I suggest you use `strtoupper` to encode the hash and `strtr` to decode it, [like this](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/64362af4f05b76c2439f91a240b388a958c3d0de/phunction/Math.php#L31).